# nativescript-vue error al depurar en android aplicacion desde cli

Tags: vue.js, nativescript

estoy empezando en nativescript vue para desarrollar apps moviles , pero al momento de correr la aplicacion para android me dice que no encuentra el proyecto, ya tengo instalado todo lo necesario (sdk,vue cli,etc), que creen que pueda ser, a alguien le ha pasado , como lo puedo resolver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

aqui esta el proyecto en mi directorio
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

este es el package.json

```
{
 "name": "tuwallet",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "A native application built with NativeScript-Vue",
 "author": "jose20161996 <josejara1996@gmail.com>",
 "license": "MIT",
 "scripts": {
             "build": "webpack --env.tnsAction build",
             "build:android": "npm run build -- --env.android",
             "build:ios": "npm run build -- --env.ios",
             "debug": "webpack --watch --env.tnsAction debug",
             "debug:android": "npm run debug -- --env.android",
             "debug:ios": "npm run debug -- --env.ios",
             "watch": "webpack --watch --env.tnsAction run",
             "watch:android": "npm run watch -- --env.android",
             "watch:ios": "npm run watch -- --env.ios",
             "clean": "rimraf dist"
 },
"dependencies": {
                 "vue-router": "^3.0.1",
                 "vuex": "^3.0.1",
                 "nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.4",
                 "nativescript-vue": "^1.3.1",
                 "tns-core-modules": "~3.4.1"
 },
"devDependencies": {
                  "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
                  "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
                  "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
                  "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
                  "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.1",
                  "css-loader": "^0.28.11",
                  "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
                  "fs-extra": "^5.0.0",
                  "nativescript-vue-externals": "^0.2.0",
                  "nativescript-vue-loader": "^0.1.5",
                  "nativescript-vue-target": "^0.1.0",
                  "nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^1.3.1",
                  "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
                  "ns-vue-loader": "^0.1.2",
                  "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
                  "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
                  "sass-loader": "^6.0.7",
                  "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.16",
                  "webpack": "^3.11.0",
                  "webpack-synchronizable-shell-plugin": "0.0.7",
                  "winston-color": "^1.0.0"
 }
}
```

Comment: Estas parado en la carpeta que corresponde?

Comment: @gbianchi si lo estoy, estuve buscando en internet y tambien aparecia que el archivo package.json puede que le falten directivas o algo asi, pero todavia no logro correr la app

Comment: entonces muestra tu package.json a ver si podemos ayudarte

Comment: sera tns run build:android lo que queres ejecutar?

Comment: @gbianchi quiero poder ver la aplicacion en el emulador de android

Comment: @gbianchi ejecute el tns run build: android y sale el mismo error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya encontré la solución, ejecutando el comando `npm run clean` en el directorio del proyecto, luego se ejecuta `npm run watch:android`  y funciona, personalmente ocupo mi móvil para ver la app.